# Supervise the output of a program using script

Tags: linux, shell

How can i write a shell script that can supervise the input and the output of a running script? 
I have another script that will generate results. I want something like trigger to run commands when the other script will generate results.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect

Comment: I should install packet expect. Expect is used if i am waiting a result a string, int the same script. I want something to control the output of another file